# How to know origin of broken source in Browser Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Suppose I open a page and it appears broken because some of resources were not loaded due to error 404 or others.

But how to know FROM WHERE these resources were requested?

For example, I have the following problematic resource in Chrome Console:

[image]

If I click to it, I get

[image]

I.e. empty pane with no any clues.

Is it possible to find another resource (HTML, Javascript and so on) who had requested this one?

Question applicable to any browser, not to Chrome only. The goal is to find "initiator" or "origin" of broken resource.

Comment: You can see initiator in `Network` panel. But often it will not be very helpful (particularly when you have minified code)

Answer (score 0):

You can see initiator in Network panel in Chrome Dev Tools - but you'll have to refresh the page first. The screenshot below I took on YouTube page (with adblocker turned on - some requests were blocked by UBlock Origin).

[image: Chrome Devtools - Youtube]

When you click the value from Initiator column, it will open Sources panel on the file. Typically the Initiator is some generic function like `doXHRequest()`, which will not tell you much in itself - you'd have to put a breakpoint there and observe when it's called and by whom.

When the code is minified, it might not be that helpful though.